# Jawbone pub sub json payload structure change

Tags: notifications, publish-subscribe, jawbone

I integrated jawbone with my app and everything was working fine.
I implemented authentication for pub sub notification according to the documentation mentioned in jawbone development portal (https://jawbone.com/up/developer/pubsub)
I followed the pub sub json payload structure given in jawbone development portal
But now I am getting different pub sub json payload structure. So my pub sub is not working.
Is there any change in pub sub json payload structure?

payload structure mentioned on development portal is like this:

```
{   
  "notification_timestamp": "1372787949",
   "events": [
    {
        "user_xid": "RGaCBFg9CsB83FsEcMY44A",
        "event_xid": "EJpCkyAtwoO0XTdkYyuTNw",
        "type": "move",
        "action": "creation" , 
        "timestamp": "1372787849",
        "secret_hash":"e570b3071a0964f9e2e69d13nd9ba19535392aaa"
    },
    {
        "user_xid": "RGaCBFg9CsB83FsEcMY44A",
        "event_xid": "blaHyAtwoO0XTdkYyuTNw",
        "type": "sleep",
        "action": "updation" , 
        "timestamp": "1372787859",
        "secret_hash":"e570b3071a0964f9e2e69d13nd9ba19535392aaa"
    }]
 }
```

Actual payload that i am getting in server is like:

```
    {
     "secret_hash": "34ba79b1512cb1bxxxxxxx",
     "events":[
      {
       "user_xid": "6HGK86qWtLJIoXXXX",
       "event_xid": "akA6KuLaNsJv8XXXXX ",
       "type": "move",
       "action": "updation",
       "timestamp": "1473145183"
  }],
"notification_timestamp": "1473145183"
```

}

Comment: Could you include the differences in the payloads in your question?

Comment: Ok, so is the issue you're facing that the secret_hash appears for the entire notification instead of within each event?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.

Comment: Just looked at the code. It's an error in the documentation. Let me fix it, and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error in the [documentation on the developer portal](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/pubsub). Thank you for pointing it out!

The examples have been updated to reflect that there is only one `secret_hash` per notification:

```
{
    "notification_timestamp": "1372787949",
    "events": [
        {
            "user_xid": "RGaCBFg9CsB83FsEcMY44A",
            "event_xid": "EJpCkyAtwoO0XTdkYyuTNw",
            "type": "move",
            "action": "creation" , 
            "timestamp": "1372787849"
        },
        {
            "user_xid": "RGaCBFg9CsB83FsEcMY44A",
            "event_xid": "blaHyAtwoO0XTdkYyuTNw",
            "type": "sleep",
            "action": "updation" , 
            "timestamp": "1372787859"
        }
    ],
    "secret_hash": "e570b3071a0964f9e2e69d13nd9ba19535392aaa",
}
```